# Hazelcast Jet logs not working after configuration

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I am new to Hazelcast and I am trying to change the logs location to file using logs4j but it seems to be not working. log file is getting created but there is no entry coming, please help how can I make it working.

```
JetConfig jetConfig = new JetConfig();
jetConfig.getHazelcastConfig().setProperty( "hazelcast.logging.type", "log4j" );
```

and log4j entry as below:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,out
log4j.appender.file=INFO,file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/opt/logs/hazelcast.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%5p] - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.file.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.category.file=INFO, file
log4j.additivity.file=false
```

Am I missing any configuration then please let me know.

Comment: If you're new to this, you'd be better starting with Hazelcast 5.0.2. It looks like you're using an older version. Also, `log4j` would be better replaced with `log4j2`. This most likely cause of your logging not working is either the Log4j classes not being on the classpath or the properties file not being found. Can you get your code to log something ? That would prove if log4j is available in general.

Comment: Thanks for response @NeilStevenson but as my application have some dependencies over log4j so I am not changing it to log4j2 and my other logs are working but when I included hazelcast it is not working let me debug it more what is wrong am I doing.

Answer (score 2):

Your log4j configuration is incorrect. I suppose you want to log into the console at ERROR level and DEBUG level to the file. To do that use the following and adjust as you need:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,out,file

log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.out.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.out.Threshold=ERROR

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/tmp/hazelcast.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%5p] - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=DEBUG

log4j.additivity.file=false
```

The key parts are

- root level set to the lowest level you need, use both appenders for the root level
- set the threshold for each appender

Comment: No I don't need Error in console I need it in file only but you answer helped me I just have to change Threshold from DEBUG to ERROR, thanks :)